# How to return the generated value of a stored procedure using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am new to hibernate i got a scenario where i need to call a stored procedure using hibernate.I am using native query to call my stored procedure.The code below is where i am setting all the parameters to the stored proc.And i declared my query in my entity.

```
ENTITY class:


      @Entity
        @NamedNativeQueries({
            @NamedNativeQuery(
            name = "callStoreProcedure",
            query = "CALL SP_INS_EPC_CERTIFICATE_EVENTS(:BUS_PARTNER_ID ,:PROVIDER_NAME,:PROVIDER_ADDR_LINE1,:PROVIDER_ADDR_LINE2 ,:PROVIDER_CITY,:PROVIDER_STATE,EPC_CERTIFICATE)",
        resultClass = DOEPCTest.class)

        })
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EPRMTADM.SP_INS_EPC_CERTIFICATE_EVENTS
(
          -- IN EPC_CERTIFICATE_ID INTEGER,
          IN P_BUS_PARTNER_ID CHAR(6),
          IN P_PROVIDER_NAME VARCHAR(80),
          IN P_PROVIDER_ADDR_LINE1 VARCHAR(80),
          IN P_PROVIDER_ADDR_LINE2 VARCHAR(80),
          IN P_PROVIDER_CITY VARCHAR(80),
          IN P_PROVIDER_STATE CHAR(2),
          OUT P_EPC_CERTIFICATE_ID INTEGER
)
```

(....INSERT Statments which sets all the values in to the PROC)

```
SET P_EPC_CERTIFICATE_ID = IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL();
```

OUT P_EPC_CERTIFICATE_ID INTEGER returns the certificate_id

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("callStoreProcedure").
                setParameter("BUS_PARTNER_ID", "0123");
                setParameter("PROVIDER_NAME", "qwe");
                query.setParameter("PROVIDER_ADDR_LINE1", "asdasd");
                query.setParameter("PROVIDER_ADDR_LINE2", "aasd");  
                query.setParameter("PROVIDER_CITY", "asd");
                query.setParameter("PROVIDER_STATE", "pa");
                        List result = query.list();
```

As my CERTIFICATE_ID is generated value i cannot set it,It is the return value.How can i handle it in hibernate.Is there any standard api which returns the 
OUT P_EPC_CERTIFICATE_ID INTEGER  out

And this is identity key generated by DB2 when i call this Store Procedure.Is there any way to get this certificate id out.I am able to set the parameters in but.I coudnt get this value out.I think i should pass some thing like.

```
   procedure.registerOutParameter(EPC_CERTIFICATE_ID , java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

But i have no idea how to do it using Query in hibernate. please suggest a best way to get the identity get out. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wont you get the certificate like this ?

```
for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++){
        DOEPCTest doepcTest = (DOEPCTest)result.get(i);
        System.out.println(doepcTest.getEPC_CERTIFICATE_ID());
    }
```